# Without expanded how can we set tabbar view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

[image]

```
   DefaultTabController(
     animationDuration: Duration.zero,
     length: 2,
     child: Column(
       children: [
         Expanded(
           flex: 1,
           child: TabBarView(
             physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
             controller: _tabController,
             children:  [
               WeekDaysTimeSlot(),
               WeekEndsTimeSlot(),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   )
```

I have used expanded to set tabbar view in full screen. But I want to make it dynamic as per data. As per data length It will fit in screen. Screen become scrollable when data will increase.

Comment: Wrap the parent widget with `SingleChildScrollView()` Not unless you want the tab bar only to be scrollable

Comment: I have user nestedscrollview as a parent widget. But, The problem is if I used container instead of expanded with Media query It covers extra space.

Comment: I want to set screen length according data length only. No extra space required.

Comment: You can see extra spacing in image.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it in SinglechildScroll View

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didnt work.